# Sending a mail to a CC (Carbon Copy) address with Amazon SES

Tags: email, amazon-ses, carbon-copy

I am sending a mail with Amazon SES.

The following mail is delivered but although the CC address is in the mail Amazon doesn't actually deliver an email to the CC'd address.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the raw email:

```
Delivered-To: personToAddres@gmail.com
Received: by xx.xxx.xxx.1x5 with SMTP id i7xxx3xxx4qaz6;
        Wed, 26 Mar 2014 04:33:49 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by xx.xxx.xx.xxx7 with SMTP id xxx5057wiw.xx8;
        Wed, 26 Mar 2014 04:33:48 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <xxx-xxxx-xxx-x9xx-xx-xxx@xxxx.amazonses.com>
Received: from xx-xxx.smtp-out.x10xx.amazonses.com (xxx.smtp-out.xxx.amazonses.com. [xx.xxx.xx.xxx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id fxxx.x11xx.xxx.xx
        for <personToAddres@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Wed, 26 Mar 2014 04:33:48 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of xxx12x-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx@xxx.amazonses.com designates xx.x15xx.x.xxx as permitted sender) client-ip=xx.xxx.x.xxx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxx-xx13x-xxx-xx-xx-xx@xxx.amazonses.com designates xx.xx16.x.x as permitted sender) smtp.mail=x14xx@.amazonses.com
Return-Path: xx17x@.amazonses.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="=xxx18x"
From: no-reply@x19xx.co
Subject: Your February Report
Cc: info@carbonCopyAddress.com
Date: Wed, 26 Mar 2014 11:33:46 +0000
Message-ID: <xx20x@xxx.amazonses.com>
X-SES-Outgoing: 2014.03.26-xx.x21xx.x.1xx

--=_xxxxx22xxx1
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="=_xxx23xxxxxxx2"

--=_xx24xxxxxxxx3
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

this is additional email text
--=_xxxxx25xxx4
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<p>Dear Mr and Mrs Peson</p>...
```

Comment: Are you running in sandbox mode?

Comment: What mechanism are you using to submit this message to SES?  SMTP? HTTP?  One of the SDKs?  Show some code, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SendRawEmailRequest to send emails, you need to make sure that cc and bcc addresses are added to Destinations collection